# vim in ubuntu terminal: "background" property is set after vimrc is loaded

Tags: ubuntu, vim, colors, gnome-terminal

I use vim in ubuntu's default terminal.
I set two terminal profiles: one named "dark" with *colors > built-in scheme > "Solarized dark"* and one named "light" with Solarized light.

In Vim I like to have the cursor line highlighted so I put this command in my `vimrc`:

```
hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=254 ctermfg=NONE
```

This highlights the cursor line with a light gray background. It's perfect when using Solarized Light, but not at all when using Solarized Dark.

Luckily and by some mechanism I do not understand, vim is aware whether I am using solarized dark or solarized light:
the `background` option is being set to "light" or "dark" accordingly.
For instance if I am using solarized light this is what happens:

```
:set background?
  background=light
```

So I thought I would use that in my `vimrc` to change the cursor line color depending on what color scheme I use:

```
set cursorline
if &background == "light"
    hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=254 ctermfg=NONE
else
    hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=238 ctermfg=NONE
endif
```

**Problem**: It doesn't work. Cursor line is always in light gray,
as if the `background` property was always set to `"light"`.

It seems that at the time when `vimrc` is loaded the `background` property has not been changed already.

Note that if I execute `source ~/.vimrc` when I am in Vim it works great, the cursor line is highlighted with the proper color.

Any idea on how to fix that?

### Config

vim 7.4.1689
GNOME Terminal 3.18.3
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu 17.04

### Edit

Note that **I do not have any `:colorscheme <something>` in my `vimrc`**: I get solarized themes via gnome terminal profiles. I don't think Vim "knows" I am using these colors; it is just that somehow some script sets vim's `background` variable according to my gnome terminal color choice.

Answer (score 1):

There is a vim plugin named `AfterColors.vim` that allows one to customize things after a color scheme is loaded. You basically need to put your highlight cursorline statement (`hi CursorLine...`) in `after/colors/common.vim` file.

From the documentation of AfterColors.vim script:

> Allows you to create an after/colors/ script for customizing any
>   colorscheme.
>
> -- EXAMPLE --  If you like the 'desert' colorscheme, but you really want comments to be red and functions to be blue, previously you would
>   copy the entire colorscheme into your home directory and customize it.
>   With this plugin installed, you can create a small script to change
>   just the parts you want for that colorscheme, exactly how you would
>   for an ftplugin or syntax script:
>
> For unix systems you would create:    ~/.vim/after/colors/desert.vim: 
>       highlight Comment guifg=Red ctermfg=Red 
>       highlight Function guifg=Blue ctermfg=Blue
>
> On windows you would create:  C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Peter\vimfiles\after\colors\desert.vim: 
>       highlight Comment guifg=Red ctermfg=Red 
>       highlight Function guifg=Blue ctermfg=Blue
>
> -- VERSION 6 WARNING --  If your Vim is older than version 7, then the after/colors scripts will only be loaded once when Vim starts.  This
>   will not be a problem if you choose your colorscheme in your .vimrc
>   file, but if you change your colorscheme after vim has loaded then
>   your after/colors scripts will be ignored.  This is not an issue in
>   Vim 7.

And,

> install details
>
> 1) Put AfterColors.vim in ~/.vim/plugin/ or $HOME\vimfiles\plugin\
>
> 2) Create your colorscheme customizations in after/colors/.vim
>
> 3) **Create global customizations (for all colorschemes) in after/colors/common.vim**

Link: [AfterColors.vim plugin home page](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1641)

Comment: Doesn't work :-( I see AfterColors.vim loaded in `:scriptnames` but `after/colors/common.vim` does not seem to load.

Answer (score 1):

You can run a command when the `background` option is modified.

In your vimrc:

```
autocmd OptionSet background call MyFunction()

function MyFunction()
    if &background == "light"
        hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=254 ctermfg=NONE
    else
        hi CursorLine   cterm=NONE ctermbg=238 ctermfg=NONE
    endif
endfunction
```

Not tested, but it should work.

---

**Bonus point** - Let's say you want to customize a syntax file, for example the `markdown.vim` syntax file. You'd create a file at `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim`, and possibly you would have some `if &background == ...` in this file. You'll bump into the same issue (this file is loaded before `background` is set), and you can fix this issue by adding this line in your `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd OptionSet background if exists("g:syntax_on") | syntax on | endif
```

With this line, when `background` is set, Vim will run `syntax on`, which basically reloads the syntax files.

Comment: Looks nice, I'll try this even if I don't really have the problem any more since I don't use Gnome terminal any more (I use Alacritty now)